# Javascript sha1 + HMCASHA1 Crypto JS encryption for .Net code

Tags: javascript, .net, sha1, cryptojs, hmacsha1

Following is how the encyption has been done on backend useing .Net.

```
public static string ShaEncrypt(string input,string keyStr) {
     byte[] key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(keyStr);
     HMACSHA1 myhmacsha1 = new HMACSHA1(key);
     byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(input);
     MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
     return myhmacsha1.ComputeHash(stream).Aggregate("", (s, e) => s + String.Format("{0:x2}", e), s => s);
}
```

For the same I need to do this in front end Javascript.
I have tried by using google code for Crypto using sha1.

```
var hash = CryptoJS.SHA1(keyString);
var test = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.Stringify(hash);
```

But I am getting CryptoJS.enc as undefined. Please help me.

Comment: Please post a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: It's highly unlikely that `CryptoJS.enc` is undefined. You probably forgot to include the CryptoJS library or its relevant parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to include the **core-min.js, enc-base64-min.js**.

Also below is the Javascript code to convert Hashed values.

```
var key = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(apiSecret);                                       
var prehash = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(apiKey);                                       
var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(prehash, key);   
return hash;
```